# Cannot find module 'C:\Users\utkar\Documents\My Project\data-visualization-dashbord\server\models\AffiliateStat.js'

Tags: module, nodemon

Error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JXDf.png): Cannot find module 'C:\Users\utkar\Documents\My Project\data-visualization-dashbord\server\models\AffiliateStat.js' imported from C:\Users[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90yHc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDVdo.png)utkar\Documents\My Project\data-visualization-dashbord\server\index.js

I am geting error message [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]